# Extract strings using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to download a html source, then search for the username and other information, and then display this in my program.
I'm pretty new to programming, but a straight noob when it comes to things like this (Regex) so I hope you can explain it to me.

I used Regex before extracting a K/D ratio from a html source, for that I used this code:

```
string pattern = @"<span class=""kdratio"">\d+\.\d+";
```

But I have no idea how to start on this one...

This is the line of the source that contains the information:

```
<section class="profile-header" profile="true" motto="user's motto" user="User" figure="hr-3322-45.hd-190-1.ch-3342-64-66.lg-285-64.sh-3068-82-66.ea-1404-64">
```

I only need the parts `user="User"` and `figure="x"`, I couldn't try anything because I really wouldn't know how to start, because the html line looks so different from what I have experience with.

Comment: `user="([^"]*?)" figure="([^"]*?)"` as regex would work ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Nkt.png). But it'd better to use an html parser to extract the values of the attributes `user` and `figure` of this `section` element, the `class="profile-header"` seems to be a good unique identifier for it. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack to get to know how to use HTMLAgility Pack to parse the html, find the node (`<section>`) and extract attributes out of it.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are not a good idea for matching HTML unless it's very simple, single, tag matching. See here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I recommend using an HTML DOM-parsing library and use XPath or CSS selectors to get the information you want. For .NET, HtmlAgilityPack is recommended. For CSS Selectors you'll want Fizzler (an add-on for HtmlAgilityPack).

In JavaScript (easily rewritten to C# and HtmlAgilityPack) it would be this:

```
document.querySelector(
    "section[class=profile-header][profile=true][user=User]"
).textContent
```

- HtmlAgilityPack: http://html-agility-pack.net
- Fizzler: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack/

Comment: Yes that's what i was afraid of... Many people suggest HtmlAgilityPack but it's always been a mystery for me what it is and how to use it, time to find it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Generally for parsing HTML, Regex is not a good choice! HTML tends to be so complicated and it is so hard to write a single Regex to be able to match everything! Instead use a parser like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).